# awk command which is not working as expected

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file input as below:

```
-4.0,vijay
-2.0,chan
-3.0,vijay
```

and my command is :

```
 awk -F, '{a[$2]=a[$2]+$1}{for (i in a) print i","a[i]}'
```

i am expecting

```
vijay,-7.0
chan,-2.0
```

the actual output is

```
vijay -4
vijay -4
chan -2
vijay -7
chan -2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
awk -F, '{arr[$2]+=$1}END{for(i in arr)print i,",",arr[i]}'
```

Comment: Oh!so i t means that just not putting the `END` is the problem.I thought that the last block will be assumed `END` as default

Comment: @zombie: Blocks with no condition run on *every* line.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to save the print until all the lines have been processed.

```
'{a[$2]=a[$2]+$1}END{for (i in a) print i","a[i]}'
```

Also try `printf` to get the comma in the right spot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the array at the END block otherwise your for loop will start to print for each record iterated.

```
awk -F, '{a[$2]+=$1}END{for (i in a) print i","a[i]}' file
```